# I have problems reading a csv file. There seem to be some non readable characters in the file but I can not find them

Tags: python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I'm writing a csv-file by reading out values from a binary file.
If I want to open the csv-file with pandas

```py
df=pd.read_csv(file)
```

im getting an error.

```py
Unable to open 'parsers.pyx': Unable to read file
(Error: File not found (c:\users\sascha\test_files\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx)).
```

The file is definitely at the given path and I am able to open it by

```py
open(file, 'w')
```

The file seems to have a line with unreadable characters at line 25 which I found out by using nrows in the read_csv.

```py
df_data = pd.read_csv('y-Values.csv', nrows=24) --> Works!
df_data = pd.read_csv('y-Values.csv', nrows=25) --> Doesn't work!
```

Im writing the file as follows:

```py
with open(name, "rb") as binary_file:
            # Values of byte 437 String: Batchnname
            binary_file.seek(436, 0)
            chargenname_bytes = binary_file.read(331)
            try: # fängt fehler beim decoden ab
                chargenname_bytes = chargenname_bytes.decode('ascii')
            except:
                continue
            chargenname_bytes = re.match(r"[\x20-\x7E]+", chargenname_bytes).group() # match printable characters using regex
            chargenname_bytes = str(chargenname_bytes.replace('  ', '_').replace(' ', '_').replace('/', '#')) # replace forbidden characters
            chargen_nummer = chargenname_bytes.split('_', 1)[0]
            try:
                chargen_typ = chargenname_bytes.split('_', 1)[1].rstrip('_')
            except:
                chargen_typ = chargenname_bytes[1].rstrip('_')
            # Path and filename to write
            output_filename_y_values = str('../csv_file/y-Values.csv')

            # Open the file with writing permission
            myfile_data = open(output_filename_y_values, 'at+')
            myfile_data.write(chargenname_bytes+',') # Write Batchname to csv
            # Write values to csv
            for i in range(0,x_anzahl_steps,1000):
                binary_file.seek(768+2*i, 0)
                y_values = int.from_bytes(binary_file.read(2), byteorder='little',signed=True)*2**y_exponent
                myfile_data.write(str(y_values)+',')
            myfile_data.write('\n')
            chargenname_bytes = ''
myfile_data.close()
binary_file.close()
```

May be there is a smarter way to write the csv. But anyway I can open it in text editor or excel but I am not able to load it into a dataframe. Any ideas?

I just recently found out that VSCode shows me also this error:

```py
ERROR TOKENIZING DATA. C ERROR: EXPECTED 10 FIELDS IN LINE 27, SAW 11
```

Comment: Specifying the encoding might be what you need: `df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding = 'utf8')`

Comment: It's not clear which character encoding you intend this file to use. Writer and reader have to agree. And, what are the bytes for line 25, please?

Comment: if any of your fields is unquoted and has a comma, it can result in above error. You can try writing and reading a tab separated file